# Curve Fitting using Numpy Polyfit, estimate constant on function with Square Root

Tags: python, numpy, curve-fitting

First of All, Sorry for my poor English and Thanks for clicking this Question.

I already have x and y data sets, so I want to do curve fitting with my data sets.

and estimated Model is [image]

then How can I estimate constants of this Model by polyfit?

I know

```
np.polyfit(x,y,1)
```

means Linear Equation Estimating. (1 means Linear)

but How can I estimate using another equation like square root with three or more constants with my data sets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `scipy.optimize.curve_fit`, here is an example how you can do this

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def func(x,a,b,c):
    return a * np.sqrt(x - b) + c

x = np.linspace(2,20,100)
y = func(x,2,-2,3)
y_true = y + 0.1*np.random.normal(size=len(x))

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func,x,y_true)
y_pred = func(x,*popt)

fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,6))
ax.scatter(x,y_true,c='r',label='true',s=6)
ax.plot(x,y_pred,c='g',label='pred')
ax.legend(loc='best')
```

this will give you

[image: result]

The array `popt` is the list of `(a,b,c)` values.

---

**UPDATE**

After testing `curve_fit` using the real dataset provided by reaver lover, I was surprised to find that `curve_fit` can fail on this relatively simple regression task.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def func(x,a,b,c):
    print('%.3f, %.3f, %.3f' % (a,b,c))
    return a * np.sqrt(x - b) + c

x = np.array([5, 11, 15, 44, 60, 70, 75, 100, 120, 200])
y_true = np.array([2.492, 8.330, 11.000, 19.394, 24.466, 27.777, 29.878, 26.952, 35.607, 46.966])

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func,x,y_true)
popt = [2.252, 5.000, 6.908]
y_pred = func(x,*popt)

fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,6))
ax.scatter(x,y_true,c='r',label='true',s=6)
ax.plot(x,y_pred,c='g',label='pred')
ax.legend(loc='best')
```

Running this script, you will find the list of coefficients `(a,b,c)` somehow becomes `(nan,nan,nan)` near the end of optimization. However, the last `(a,b,c)` that is not `(nan,nan,nan)` found by `curve_fit` has already been good enough, as you can see in the plot

[image: output]

I'm really clueless why `curve_fit` can fail.

Comment: Thank you for answer me,
but I already have x, y data like
`x = [5, 11, 15, 44, 60, 70, 75, 100, 120, 200]
y = [2.492, 8.330, 11.000, 19.394, 24.466, 27.777, 29.878, 26.952, 35.607, 46.966]`then how can i apply with this data?

Comment: @reaverlover You are welcome, I tested `curve_fit` on your data, and I was surprised to find `curve_fit` failed on this task. I have updated my post, maybe someone may help us to solve this.

Answer (score 3):

What you are trying to do is

```
    a*np.sqrt(x-b) + c ~ y
<=> np.sqrt(x-b) ~ (y-c)/a     # not entirely true, but close
<=> x - b ~ (y/a - c/a)**2
<=> x ~ (y/a - c/a)** 2 + b
```

The last row means to approximate `x` as a quadratic polynomial in `y`. So

```
np.polyfit(y,x, 2)
```